# French equivalents of the ironic German expression "Du beliebst zu scherzen!"

Tags: expressions, allemand

> Du **beliebst** zu scherzen! Nichts liegt mir ferner!

- *You just **love** to joke! {/ you've got to be joking!} Nothing is further from my mind!*

We were having a conversation in German, and I'm wondering how the same idea is commonly/idiomatically expressed in French?

In German, the verb "lieben" is as straightforward as "love/like sth.", while "belieben" shares a similar meaning and yet is often used **ironically**, the implication being that you think your interlocutor might actually not be joking...

"**Mais c'est une blague ou quoi !**" or "**Mais on blague ou quoi !**" sprang to mind as its French equivalent, but is there a better alternative that conveys the ironic sense of "belieben"?

Comment: Maybe something like "t'aimes rigoler" or "tu me fais rire". But said with a straight face.

Answer (score 2):

Comme proposé dans la question :

> C'est une blague ?

est une possibilité. Je préfère ici le point d'interrogation, je dis ça avec l'intonation de la question.

Mais on peut aussi dire :

> C'est une plaisanterie !  (?)

Et aussi bien comme une question que comme une exclamation (du moins en ce qui me concerne) :

> Tu plaisantes ! / Tu veux plaisanter !

> Tu ne parles pas sérieusement !

> T'es pas sérieux !

> Tu veux rire !

> Tu te moques (de moi) !

> Tu me fais marcher !

ou entre copains et c'est très très familier :

> Tu te fiches de moi !

Et encore un degré plus familier :

> Tu te fous de moi !

Comment: Surprisingly *rigoler* isn't mentioned yet: *Tu rigoles, toi ! (?)*

Comment: @FrankfromFrankfurt Hi. Care to put in your two cents, as a native German speaker? :) Do you find "*Tu rigoles, toi ! (?)*" best suited?

Comment: @Con-gras-tue-les-chiens: C'est pourquoi, j'ai publié un commentaire et pas une réponse. La traduction me paraît la plus naturelle et une que j'avais souvent entendu. (Souvent par d'autres étudiants étrangers, il faut l'admettre.) Elle me paraît mieux que "Tu te moques (de moi).", voire "Tu te fous/fiches de moi." Je percois la phrase allemande comme plutôt amicale (on se tutoye !).

Answer (score 0):

As an ironical expression is expected, I might suggest :

> *Très drôle !*